# Issue with Outlook Event for New Mail

Tags: vba, email, outlook

[image: Outlook Inbox Image]

I would like to do some operation when a new mail comes to mailbox. For that I am using Item_Add() Event

```
Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
   ... Do Something
Exit Sub
```

***Can anyone tell me How to set the Handler for "inbox" folder under "gilbertojperera@gmail.com"?***

**Problem:**

The issue I am facing here is that this even get fired only when a new mail comes in "Inbox" folder under "Outlook Data File". But I used to receive mails in the other "Inbox" folder marked by second red arrow (third last folder)

Due to this problem My Item_Add() event is not being triggered & resulting to my outlook macro Fail.

Please do help if you have some valuable inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you only initialized the handler for the Inbox DefaultFolder (olFolderInbox). You also must add a handler to the Inbox folder for gilbertojperera@gmail.com.

Comment: Any idea how to set handler for the gmail inbox folder ?

Comment: So you can get a reference to the folder with the following:        Dim f As Folder
Set f = Application.Session.Folders.Item(" gilbertojperera@gmail.com").Folders.Item("Inbox")

If you declare:
Public WithEvents Inbox2Items as Outlook.Items

you can then set Inbox2Items:

Set Inbox2Items = f.Items

And you can then catch events:
'code'
Private Sub Inbox2Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
...
End Sub
'code'